# How to pass form value to another page based on the clone id Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a form with id call user_form3, then i was using jquery clone to clone out different id, class and name. But the main problem is that i cannot pass the id or name value to backend because the system do not know the id or name because it was using clone to clone out.
Then i have tried using ajax to pass the form value by id but it give me the data is blank. I need some help thank you. Code is below.

This is html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>8D Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="css/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>
<style>
#t2
{
    border-bottom : 3px solid black;    
}
#th
{
    text-align:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="user_form3">
        <table id ="t2" width = "100%">
            <tr>
            <th><p style ="text-aligh:left"><b>KAMAYA ELECTRIC (M) SDN. BHD.<br>(Company No : 217941-T)</b></p></th>
            <th>Date : <?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); $year = date("Y"); $month = date("m"); $day = date("d");$Tdate = $year."-".$month."-".$day; echo $Tdate; ?></strong><br>Ref : <?php echo $id;?><br>Status : <?php //echo $Status;?> </th>
            </tr>
        </table>

    
        <table style="width:100%;" id="D4">
            <tr>
                <th id="th"> Discipline 4 : Failure Analysis</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="button" name="add_btn" id = "add_btn">+</button>
        

    <div id="clone_table">
        <table style="width: 100%;" id = "D4_1">
            
            <tr class="tablerow_1_1">
                <th class = "column1" style ="width: 5%;" >4.1</th>
                <th class = "column2" style ="width: 45%;" ><input type = "text" id = "title1" autocomplete="off"></th>
                <th style ="width: 50%;" >Attachment <span id="cancel_btn"></span></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tablerow_1_2">
                <th style ="width: 5%;" ><button type="button" name="addsubbtn_1" class = "addsubbtn_1">subtitle</button><span id="deletesub_btn"></span></th>
                <th style ="width: 45%;"><input type = "text" class = "subinputtext" id = "subtitle1_D4_1" autocomplete="off"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="tablerow_1_3">
                <td></td>
            <td><textarea name="txtarea_a" class = "txtareatext" id="txtareaD4_1_1_a" cols="50" rows="5" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>

            <td>

            <div id='upload-formD4_1_1' class = 'upload4_1_1'>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldD4_1_1">  
                        <!--<tr class="fileNDeletebtn_">  
                        </tr>-->  
                    </table>
                    <div id="fileD4_1_1_1" class = 'uploadfile4_1_1'>
                    <input class='file-inputt1' type='file' id='docD4_1_1_1' name='fileD4_1a[]' onchange="ValidateSingleInput2(this);selectFile2(this);" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"><!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" class='image4_1_1' name="fileD4_1a[]" id="fileToUploadD4_1a" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" multiple = "multiple" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="button" value="Images" onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUploadD4_1a').click();" />
                    <div class = "preview" id="previewD4_1_a"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="clone_table">
        <table style="width: 100%;" id = "D4_1sample">
            <tr class="stablerow_1_1">
                <th class = "column1" style ="width: 5%;" >4.1</th>
                <th class = "column2" style ="width: 45%;" ><input type = "text" class="inputtext" id = "title1" autocomplete="off"></th>
                <th style ="width: 50%;" >Attachment <span id="cancel_btn"></span></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_2">
                <th style ="width: 5%;" ><button type="button" name="addsubbtn_1" class = "addsubbtn_1">subtitle</button><span id="deletesub_btn"></span></th>
                <th style ="width: 45%;"><input type = "text" class = "subinputtext" id = "subtitle1_D4_1" autocomplete="off"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="stablerow_1_3">
                <td></td>
            <td><textarea class = "txtareatext" name="txtarea_a" id="txtareaD4_1_1_a" cols="50" rows="5" autocomplete="off"></textarea></td>

            <td>

            <div id='upload-formD4_1_1' class = 'upload4_1_1'>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldD4_1_1">  
                        <!--<tr class="fileNDeletebtn_">  
                        </tr>-->  
                    </table>
                    <div id="fileD4_1_1_1" class = 'uploadfile4_1_1'>
                    <input class='file-inputt1' type='file' id='docD4_1_1_1' name='fileD4_1a[]' onchange="ValidateSingleInput2(this);selectFile2(this);" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"><!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" class='image4_1_1' name="fileD4_1a[]" id="fileToUploadD4_1a" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" multiple = "multiple" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="button" value="Images" onclick="document.getElementById('fileToUpload4_1a').click();" />
                    <div class = "preview" id="previewD4_1_a"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" style="font-size:1.5vw"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Email <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </div>
                <br />
    
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="user_data">
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <br><br>    
                <div class="text-center text-md-center">
                    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send</a>
                </div>

                <div id="user_dialog" title="Add Data">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Department: </label>
                <?php
                    echo "<select name='select_catalog' id='select_catalog'>
                    <option>All</option>";
                     
                    $sqli = "SELECT DISTINCT SecCodeName FROM user ORDER BY SecCodeName ASC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqli);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo '<option>'.$row['SecCodeName'].'</option>';
                    }
                    
                    echo '</select>';
                ?>
                
                <br>
                <label>Enter Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" list="o1"/>
                <datalist id="o1" autocomplete="off">
                    <div id="result2" class="result2"></div>
                </datalist>
                <span id="error_first_name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="hidden_row_id" />
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="action_alert" title="Action"></div>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the submit function it gave me data is blank when i alert it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myform = document.getElementById("user_form3");
        var fd = new FormData(myform);
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"uploadD4_D8.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:fd,
            //dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,   
            success:function(data){ 
                alert(data);
                /*if(data != "")
                {
                    window.location.href = "login.php";
                }*/
                
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) 
            {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The submit function it give me the data is blank when i alert out. Do i need to display something in the uploadD4_D8.php? really need help on that thanks.

Comment: Make a summary, not everyone gonna read all of that. Remove redundant parts link CSS, metas and such.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try hidden input that stores data what you want to send to AJAX URL.
With jQuery you can get > `$('selector').attr('id')`